# Get only current view focus

Tags: android, view

In my case user should not click on any other view, while current view is active (image preview)

How do i set the focus only on current view? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you have view above another view you can simply give blank click to top view so that bottom view will not be accessed.

Simply give onClick to the parent layout of above view.

```
android:onClick="doNothing";
```

And then in actvity just define the method doNothing.

```
public void doNothing(View view)
{

}
```